# Need to make container accessible from host with ip assigned to container by docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to setup docker container on Linux so that it's accessible right from host on Windows 10 with container's ip?

My docker compose file is simple

```
version: '2'
services:
  silo1:
    hostname: silo1
    image: 'silo'
    ports: 
        - '11111:11111'
        - '30000:30000'
```

Now to check container's ip address I run

```
# hostname -I
172.20.0.2
#
```

This container runs the service that is accessible from other containers on subnetwork 172.20.0.*, but my host computer on Windows 10 where Dockers are ran from can't ping the ip by any port including 11111, 30000

```
paping.exe 172.20.0.2 on TCP 11111:
Connection timed out
```

My host machine shows the following Network information:

```
IPv4 address: 192.168.0.22
IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
```

Maybe the problem caused by host and container being on different local subnets? Is so, how can I configure docker container to assign 192.168.0.* ip to my container? I wonder how container picks port for containers, why is it 172.20* specifically?

I know that those ports are open through host machine, like container's service must be accessible with 192.168.0.22:11111, but I need to use ip assigned to container, not a host system.

Answer (score 0):

Docker assigns IP addresses from its default bridge (172.20.0.0/16 in your case).

But Docker also let's you create a custom bridge network where you can choose the IP range.

More info here: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Comment: thanks. 1) can I set up the custom bridge network to be on the same subnet as my host 2) would I be able to access container with it IP from the host system then?